# Encoding warnings when sending data to QueueTrigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, protobuf-net, queuetrigger

I just updated Azure.Storage.Queues to the latest version, the old version I was running used the CloudQueue object, and the AddMessageAsync method to put a message on the queue.
In the new version you need to use the QueueClient and SendMessageAsync method.

I send this message from an IoTHub, when the message arrives at the iothub it is protobuf byte array.
Before the update I could just pass on the byte array to the queue. but now the new method takes either string or BinaryData.

I now pass on BinaryData that is encoded with base64, which I set in the QueueClient options (see pic).
[image: QueueOptions]

But when i receive the message in my QueueTrigger i get these warnings (see pic)
[image: warnings]

Anyone know why I'm getting these warnings? the data is arriving as it should so no problem, just curious why these warnings are coming.

Edit, More info how i send from IoTHub and how i receiving in the QueueTrigger:

Sending from IoTHub (message.EventBody is BinaryData type):
[image]

QueueTrigger:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*1. Create a storage account in azure*

[image]

*2. And in storage account create a queue*

[image]

*Install the nuGet  `Azure.Storage.Queues`*

[image]

*Used the namespace *Azure.Storage.Queues*
and have used the same code*

[image]

```
client = new QueueClient(QueueAccessKey, "msgqueue",
                new QueueClientOptions
                { 
                    MessageEncoding=QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
                });

                Console.WriteLine("Message sending to queue...");
                await client.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

[image]

*Message from the Azure Queue*

[image]

*worked in both console application and azure functions and able to send messages without any issues.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont have any trouble setting everything up. As u see i'm getting some kind of encoding warning when i receive the message in the Queue.

Comment: But I do not see any encoding warning.

Comment: I do send a Byte Array the whole way, have you tried that? And more specifically protobuf.

Comment: As an alternative way for converting the message to Base64 by creating the client with an QueueClientOptions with MessageEncoding set to QueueMessageEncoding.Base64.

For example:
_que = new QueueClient(con_String, que_Name, new QueueClientOptions
{
    MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
});
var msg = "some message";
await _que.SendMessageAsync(msg);

Comment: Thats exactly what im doing? :)